# Trouble counting keys in a json file

Tags: java, json

I am having a little trouble trying to count the number of keys contained in a json file, specially with the keys that are duplicated since they are only being counted once.

Im opening/reading the file like so:

```
String line = "";
String fileContents = "";

try {
  reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
  throw new LicensingException("Error: input file not found. ");

}

try {
  while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    fileContents += line;
  }
} catch (IOException ex) {
  throw new LicensingException("Error: input file could not be accessed.");
}

try {
  reader.close();
} catch (IOException ex) {
  throw new LicensingException("Error: input file could not be closed.");
}
```

And creating the JsonObject like so:

```
JsonObject jsonLicense = null;
StringReader sr = new StringReader(fileContents); 
jsonLicense = Json.createReader(sr).readObject();
```

After doing this, I proceed to count the number of keys in the object:

```
  int i = 0;

  for (String key: jsonLicense.keySet()) {
    i++;
  }
```

But as I said before, this only works when all the keys are different as soon as I duplicate a key they key is only counted once.

The json file Im trying to count the keys from:

```
{"Station Name" : "Hello",
"Person in charge": "this",
"EMail": "is@an.com", 
"Machine Name": "example",
"Type of License": "Starship",
"Type of License": "All"
}
```

Comment: I know duplicate keys in a JSON file is "technically valid", but I'd strongly recommend you use an array instead.

Comment: Where is Json.createReader coming from, and if you wrote it yourself, then where is the code?

Comment: You might want to rethink this. The way keys work inherently makes this a difficult task that will likely require a hacky solution.

Comment: Is JsonObject part of any library? Can you use an iterator instead of keySet?

Comment: @Pacane I'll inform myself and give it a try thank you!

Comment: @PepePeep look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Form your JSON to treat multiple values as arrays like this:

```
{
"Station Name" : "Hello",
"Person in charge": "this",
"EMail": "is@an.com", 
"Machine Name": "example",
"Types of License": ["Starship", "All"]
}
```

and then count the number of values associated with each key rather than the keys.

Comment: This may work but I was doing this in order to find out which keys were duplicated since thats the main goal. My first idea to do so was to create a `switch (key)` inside the `for` loop where each case would be one of the possible keys such as _Machine Name_ and add 1 every time Id found it. But it did not work so I tried to simplify it by trying to only count the number of keys in the file.

Comment: If you go the array approach you can find duplicates by simply seeing which keys have more than one value associated with them. This is the preferred approach for sure.